# grid overflows in Google Chrome

Tags: css, layout, sass, overflow, css-grid

I am making a list of items (cards) using grid, and the subgrid overflows into the next element element. Now, In Firefox, I don't have this problem. here is the code for the grid parent adn subgrid:

```
  .grid-parent{
     display: grid;
        margin-top: 2rem;
        grid-template-columns: 26rem [main-start]repeat(5, 1fr[main-end]);
        grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr min-content max-content;
    }

    grid-child{
      grid-column: 2/-1;
            grid-row: 1/-1;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min-content, 30rem));
            grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, 1fr);
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: start;
            padding: 0 3%;
            grid-gap: 2%;
        }

    .big-btn{
       grid-column: 1/-1;
        width: 40%;
        padding: 1rem 0;
        font-size: 2.6rem;
        @extend .fw-700;
}
```

[image: This, exactly]

Comment: tow issue related to the precentage used with grid-gap and also padding

Comment: realated (probably a duplicate) https://stackoverflow.com/q/53563613/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/53536266/8620333

Comment: not my case, as that case is with ULs and Flex, this is with grid :/

Comment: I linked to 2 questions, one with grid and percentage gap and another with percentage padding where it doesn't matter if it's flexbox or CSS grid because the behavior is the same. By the way you need to share you full code so we can see the issue

Comment: Thabk you so much, dude, the percentage Gap was the problem, now, the issue is that I don't understand why, but it solved my problem!

Comment: read the link I have shared to understand why. I have closed the question as duplicate with that link

Answer (score -1):

Try to put a margin-bottom on the big-btn?

Comment: Not working, and there is another problem, I need a fluid solution, as I don't kow how many items will the server show, and if I solve it for only n number of cards, if the number changes, it will break the design again :/

Comment: This is more of a comment, than an answer.