# Chrome / Firefox percentage height differences in CSS Grid

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, css-grid

Please note, the following problem can be solved by using fr units instead of % and auto, but I am looking for an explanation as to why the problem occurs in the first place.

In my code below,

**Firefox**: Does not obey the values for `grid-template-rows`. Applies an equal height to each row but the grid items do not overflow the container.

**Chrome**: Seems to obey the `grid-template-rows` property but the grid items overflow the container.

Initially I thought the issue was with *%* but it is an allowable unit for the row. I swapped out the *auto* value for *10%* but that created its own problem.

I've looked at the documentation but I'm missing something.

Anyone have a straight-forward explanation?

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 30% 30%;
  grid-template-rows: 30% auto 60%;
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
  <div class="box">C</div>
  <div class="box">D</div>
  <div class="box">E</div>
  <div class="box">F</div>
  <div class="box">G</div>
  <div class="box">H</div>
  <div class="box">I</div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/caseyc/pen/xQvEvo)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a known issue where the % value is calculated differently by different broswers on rendering. Can't find it now...but I'm sure I've seen it before.

Comment: Then again - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090726/the-difference-between-percentage-and-fr-units-in-css-grid-layout

Answer (score 1):

> Initially I thought the issue was with *%* but it is an allowable unit
>   for the row. I swapped out the *auto* value for *10%* but that created
>   its own problem. Anyone have a straight-forward explanation?

The problem actually is the use of `%` units.

The straightforward explanation is that percentage lengths are processed differently across browsers *when there is no defined or inherited length on the parent container*.

Therefore, because the grid container has no defined height, browsers will render the row heights, which are defined with percentages, inconsistently.

These variations are explored in detail in these posts:

- [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276)
- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

The simple solution is to **define a height on the container**. In my example below, I've added `height: 300px` to `.wrapper`. Now the rows render the same across browsers.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 300px; /* new */
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 30% 30%;
  grid-template-rows: 30% auto 60%;
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
  <div class="box">C</div>
  <div class="box">D</div>
  <div class="box">E</div>
  <div class="box">F</div>
  <div class="box">G</div>
  <div class="box">H</div>
  <div class="box">I</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Chrome: Seems to obey the grid-template-rows property but the grid
>   items overflow the container.

I would better say that chrome is doing an *effort* to have this working as the calculation is somehow complex and we have a cycle. Basically percentage value need to be resolved and initially (since there is no height defined) the browser cannot resolve the values of `grid-template-rows` so it will first cacluate the height of the wrapper based on its content (ignoring `grid-template-rows`) and we will obtain something like below:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.wrapper').offsetHeight);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 30% 30%;
  /*grid-template-rows: 30% auto 60%;*/
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
  <div class="box">C</div>
  <div class="box">D</div>
  <div class="box">E</div>
  <div class="box">F</div>
  <div class="box">G</div>
  <div class="box">H</div>
  <div class="box">I</div>
</div>
```

This is the step at where Firefox is stopping but chrome will try to do more! Note the value of the height we obtained (`194px`). Now we can resolve the percentage values based on this value and you will have this:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.wrapper').offsetHeight);
console.log(document.querySelector('.box:first-child').offsetHeight);
console.log(document.querySelector('.box:last-child').offsetHeight);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 30% 30%;
  grid-template-rows: 30% auto 60%;
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
  <div class="box">C</div>
  <div class="box">D</div>
  <div class="box">E</div>
  <div class="box">F</div>
  <div class="box">G</div>
  <div class="box">H</div>
  <div class="box">I</div>
</div>
```

Note how the first element (the first row) is having a height equal to `58px` (`0.3 * 194px`) and how the last child (the last row) is having a height equal to `117px` (`0.6 * 194px`). Logically the second row should have a height of `194px - 58px - 117px - 20px(gap) = -1` which is not enough so it will have a bigger height thus the overflow.

The overflow isn't really an issue but a side effect of this *complex* calculation and you will always have it unless you define a percentage value for each row less than (`100% - 20px/3 = 33.33% - 6.67px`).

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.wrapper').offsetHeight);
console.log(document.querySelector('.box:first-child').offsetHeight);
console.log(document.querySelector('.box:last-child').offsetHeight);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 30% 30%;
  grid-template-rows: 20% 20% 20%;
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
  <div class="box">C</div>
  <div class="box">D</div>
  <div class="box">E</div>
  <div class="box">F</div>
  <div class="box">G</div>
  <div class="box">H</div>
  <div class="box">I</div>
</div>
```

Also the browser won't get back to fix this issue by increasing the height of the wrapper as we will have a cycle since `grid-template-rows` was defined based on it.

---

Similar question: [Grid gap percentage without height](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53563613/8620333)