# Weird behavior of css grid in Chrome browser?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, css-grid

I'm observing different behavior of this code in Chrome and in Firefox:
HTML :

```css
.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 40px 50px 500px 50px 40px;
    grid-template-rows: 25% 100px auto;
    background-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">4</div>
  <div class="item item-5">5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">6</div>
  <div class="item item-7">7</div>
  <div class="item item-8">8</div>
  <div class="item item-9">9</div>
  <div class="item item-10">10</div>
  <div class="item item-11">11</div>
  <div class="item item-12">12</div>
</div>
```

#### So,  in Chrome:

- items 11 and 12 **do not have** violet background (why?)
- height of first row is 34.2px (why? )

#### In Firefox:

- items 11 and 12 **do have** violet background (as it should be in my
  opinion)
- height of first row is 18.4px  which is a height of the item in div, and
  it's  a right behavior in my opinion

Any ideas  why  this is happening ?

Comment: it's all about the percentage used in the first row ... you don't have a reference for it

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, i understand that but  i think that height in this case should be the same in both browsers

Comment: Firefox is simply ignoring the percentage value and compute the value as auto whereas chrome is doing an extra effort to compute that value based on the height of the row defined before the percentage (auto) thus you have the overflow. Both behavior are logical

Comment: closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53658807/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif  i see, how about background issue ?

Comment: the background issue is due to the overflow. When chrome is calculating the percentage height based on the first height defined you will have overflow, so content will be pushed outside

Comment: the related question seems to be a good duplicate, I am also explaining the overflow and background issue ... Michael_B is also giving a good explanation with some reference

Answer (score 0):

If there is no Height specified to the ".container" grid then percentage will be treated as auto. I think that is the reason for this behavior.

```css
.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 40px 50px 500px 50px 40px;
    grid-template-rows: auto 100px auto;
    background-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">4</div>
  <div class="item item-5">5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">6</div>
  <div class="item item-7">7</div>
  <div class="item item-8">8</div>
  <div class="item item-9">9</div>
  <div class="item item-10">10</div>
  <div class="item item-11">11</div>
  <div class="item item-12">12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not explain background issue